# Anchor HREF not Updating when Javascript Variable Changes

Tags: javascript, variables

So I'm having some issues with some links I'm injecting into a menu, where the variable in the HREF isn't being updated. I've put together a sloppy example with JSFiddle

The HREF to the added links doesn't update though based on the "hover me" data seen in the user data output below. It remains undefined. I can just wrap the "menu" variable in a function and return it, then just use menu()[i], but I am wanting to avoid that.

[http://jsfiddle.net/KnightYoshi/FEVJQ/2/]
    Note: you'll have to mouseover the "hover me" twice to get it to add the extra links, it's not as smooth as the site I'm applying it to (hence sloppy example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update the href on the event. The `href: 'http://:directory/' + uid` is not creating a binding, it is a one time setting.

Comment: Gah! Such a simple oversight. The problem is, I will need the array later, so I can't just put it into the on mousover event, and there will be more links as well. Suggestion of a better way to have it update?

Comment: As a start you should make the menu generation a function, which takes the uid as a parameter.